# How would you find the 'GOOD' ID when cancellation is involved?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose you have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(
  ID INT,
  CXL INT
 )

 INSERT INTO Data (ID, CXL)
 SELECT 1, NULL
 UNION
 SELECT 2, 1
 UNION
 SELECT 3, 2
 UNION
 SELECT 5, 3
 UNION 
 SELECT 6, NULL
 UNION
 SELECT 7, NULL
 UNION
 SELECT 8, 7
```

The column CXL is the ID that cancels a particular ID. So, for example, the first row in the table with ID:1 was good until it was cancelled by ID:2 (CXL column). ID:2 was good until it was cancelled by ID:3. ID:3 was good until it was cancelled by ID:5 so in this sequence the last "GOOD" ID was ID:5.

**I would like to find all the "GOOD" IDs** So in this example it would be:

```
Latest GOOD ID
     5
     6              
     8
```

Here's a fiddle if you want to play with this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68ac48/1

Comment: The only way I could think of doing this is to infinitely join the rows one to the other to determine the chain. This won't work though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT D.ID 
FROM Data D
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                  FROM Data WHERE D.ID = CXL)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! I changed the question a bit because I needed to do another trick here which I can't figure out how to join to your idea.

Comment: You will need to ask another question for this, you cannot update your questions to , you can add more context to it but not change the whole question. That will probably invalidate all the existing answers. Post another question. Thank you.

Comment: Would you be able to modify your answer? I don't want to duplicate post this question. The answers are still good, they partially answer the question.

Comment: This little modification in your question changes a lot. Like I said before you can expand on your question by adding more explanation on your problem but not change your Question/Problem/requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Id 
from data 
where Id not in (select cxl from data where cxl is not null)
```

Comment: This is close but had to put an ISNULL which isn't so great. Can you think of how to eliminate the ISNULL?

Comment: Since there are NULLs in the CXL column `IN` operator will return unexpected results.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!