# How would you find the 'GOOD' ID when cancellation is involved as well as the original ID that started it all?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**PLEASE DO NOT MARK THE QUESTION AS DUPLICATE WITHOUT READING IT. I DID POST A SIMILAR QUESTION BUT THE STACKOVERFLOW COMMUNITY MEMBERS ASKED ME TO REPOST THE MODIFIED QUESTION SEPARATELY AS THE SOLUTION IS MUCH MORE COMPLICATED GIVEN A SMALL, SUBTLE MODIFICATION.**

Suppose you have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(
  ID INT,
  CXL INT
 )

 INSERT INTO Data (ID, CXL)
 SELECT 1, NULL
 UNION
 SELECT 2, 1
 UNION
 SELECT 3, 2
 UNION
 SELECT 5, 3
 UNION 
 SELECT 6, NULL
 UNION
 SELECT 7, NULL
 UNION
 SELECT 8, 7
```

The column CXL is the ID that cancels a particular ID. So, for example, the first row in the table with ID:1 was good until it was cancelled by ID:2 (CXL column). ID:2 was good until it was cancelled by ID:3. ID:3 was good until it was cancelled by ID:5 so in this sequence the last "GOOD" ID was ID:5.

**I would like to find the "GOOD" ID as well as the original ID that started EACH chain.** So in this example it would be:

```
Original ID | Latest GOOD ID
     1              5
     6              6
     7              8
```

Here's a fiddle if you want to play with this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68ac48/1

Comment: I've successfully avoided cursors for the most part, only writing about 5 in my career.  This might be the sixth.  Is your data set really big?

Comment: oh yeah, it's a lot of data! There's got to be a way to do this without cursors.. I just can't think of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you find the 'GOOD' ID when cancellation is involved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287748/how-would-you-find-the-good-id-when-cancellation-is-involved)

Comment: @DeanOC - the community wanted to have a separate question. See discussion on the answer.

Comment: No time to write an example but look at recursive CTEs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took me a few minutes to dredge up the right CTE for this:

```
WITH ids AS (
  SELECT 
    ID,
    ID AS orig FROM Data d1 WHERE CXL IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    d2.ID,
    orig
  FROM ids i
  INNER JOIN Data d2 ON d2.CXL = i.ID
)

SELECT 
  orig AS [Original Id],
  MAX(ID) AS [Latest Good Id]
FROM ids
GROUP BY orig
```

[Here's your SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68ac48/36)

**This assumes that a cancelling ID is always higher than the ID it cancels, of course...**

Basically, every time it recurses, it reselects the original id again for the row.  Once the recursion is done, it's just a matter of a simple `GROUP BY` to get the original id and the most current.

Comment: @Denis the execution plan is the same either way you do the join (you can verify this on the fiddle), variances in execution times will likely have to do with other factors like memory availability and CPU load at the time the query is run.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do it using a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT ID AS Parent, ID, CXL, 0 AS level
   FROM Data
   WHERE CXL IS NULL

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT c.Parent AS Parent, d.ID, d.CXL, level = level + 1
   FROM CTE AS c 
   INNER JOIN Data AS d ON c.ID = d.CXL
)
SELECT Parent AS OriginalID, ID AS GoodID
FROM CTE AS c
WHERE level = (SELECT MAX(level) FROM CTE WHERE Parent = c.Parent)
```

The anchor query of the `CTE` selects all the original IDs that start EACH chain, i.e. the ones having `CXL NULL`. Then we recursively build up each chain, keeping `Parent` field and using `level` so as to be able to identify the end of the chain using `MAX` in the final query.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d63d6/1)

Comment: I wish I could mark this also as an answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Well, Paul's answer is simpler because it uses the assumption that *a cancelling ID is always higher than the ID it cancels*. My answer may be useful to another situation where this assumption does not hold!

Comment: What @GiorgosBetsos said.  That's an important assumption in my answer (as I noted).  This is a more general solution.

Comment: Paul's assumption does hold true in my case because you can't cancel an ID that hasn't been created yet. So a cancellingID is always higher than the ID it cancels in my scenario but I see @GiorgosBetsos point that his solution would be applicable if that scenario wasn't true so definitely voting for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this procedurally following something along the lines of the following pseudocode:

- Create tables Remaining, Good
- Copy Data into Remaining
- Copy all rows from Remaining that have a value for ID that appears nowhere in the CXL column into Good
- Delete those rows from Remaining
- While Remaining has > 0 rows

  - Inner join Good to Remaining on Good.CXL = Remaining.ID
  - Update Good.CXL for rows in the join to Remaining.CXL
  - Delete rows in the join from Remaining